# Period effect in crossover design

Tags: interaction, clinical-trials, crossover-study

I am confused with period effect, secular change, temporal trends in crossover design.

In this [article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3059315/) it is stated that

> The randomization of the treatment sequence helps to account for
> temporal trends (such as seasonal variation).

But for example, in Stephen Senn's book on cross-over trials, he says:

> Alternatively, during the time in which the cross-over trial is run
> the condition of the patients might suffer a *secular change* (some
> factors other than treatment might be slowly be affecting the
> condition of most patients) and then the benefit (or otherwise) of one
> drug compared to the other might be dependent on the current state of
> the patient. This would provide a case of period by treatment
> interaction.

So does the first link roughly say randomization can solve the issue? Or am I confused between period effect and period by interaction effect?

Answer (score 0):

The first quote talks about a period main effect with a consistent difference between the treatments across the periods. E.g. something like these means:

| Treatment | Period | Mean outcome |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 0 |
| B | 1 | 1 |
| A | 2 | 5 |
| B | 2 | 6 |

In the second case, we would have a treatment by period interaction (and probably also a period main effect) meaning that the treatment effect is not the same across periods. E.g. something like these means

| Treatment | Period | Mean outcome |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 0 |
| B | 1 | 1 |
| A | 2 | 5 |
| B | 2 | 10 |

The first case is not really a problem, at all, while the second one is trickier to deal with. In particular, it may be hard to figure out why a period by treatment interaction occurs (e.g. it could be a carry-over effect of the period 1 treatment, it could be the sort of thing Senn described with patients getting more - or less - benefit from a treatment based on some underlying state that changed over time etc.).